# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow - result within int64 range

Tags: .net, variables

I am getting an exception saying "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow", but I'm not sure why.

I am trying to do the following calculation

myvalue = 2 * 11 * 37 * 41 * 41 * 41 * 41

which equals 2,300,169,454.  I have declared the myvalue variable as Long, and also tried Int64, so this should be within the range.  Are there any other reasons why this exception is thrown?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You've declared the *target of the assignment* as `long`, but it looks like you're performing `int` arithmetic within the operation. When all the arithmetic is done as `int`, it *does* overflow. If you need the arithmetic to be performed in 64 bits, you need the operands to be `long` values - or at least some of them. (It's hard to say exactly where to change things without seeing your real code.)

Comment: Thanks!  That was exactly the issue, the operands were declared as int.  Appreciate the quick answer, another .net lesson learned!

Answer (score 1):

As you are getting that error, all the values that you are using are `int` values (or smaller).

If you just use one `long` value in the calculation, the result is a `long` value and there is no overflow:

```
long myvalue = 2 * 11 * 37 * 41 * 41L * 41 * 41;
```